# Docusign Request the Authorization Code related query

Tags: docusignapi

I have checked Docusign Request the Authorization Code related documentation and set all the settings on Docusign Admin. But when I run the below url in the browser it wants login details and accept screen. My query is how can I skip this login and accept steps. Here is the request url

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=YOUR_REQUESTED_SCOPES&client_id=YOUR_INTEGRATION_KEY
&state=YOUR_CUSTOM_STATE&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot skip this login page if you are using the authorization grant flow as this is part of the oauth protocol security. To get a token, you need to authenticate (or your customer/user would need to). This token is typically valid for 8 hours and a cookie is stored on the device which means you won't be asked again to login for the next 8 hours, but you do need to do this initially.